# how does UBIFS get starting point?

Tags: filesystems, embedded-linux, flash-memory, ubifs

I know that UBIFS' superblock (starting point) is situated at LEB 0.
but how does kernel (or U-boot) knows where to look at?
I've heard that UBI volume maps PEB and LEB randomly, but I think user should know where physical entry point is located.
I couldn't find any explanation in Google.

please help. thank you.

Comment: A UBIFS doesn't exist in a vacuum.  It is contained in a UBI volume, which in turn is contained in a MTD partition/device.  Study the [MTD, UBI, & UBIFS FAQs](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/faq/general.html)

Comment: @sawdust I think 'UBI volume table' should stored in flash somewhere, but how does UBI knows where to look at?

Comment: Study the **ubiformat** and **ubimkvol** commands.  Also see http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/ubi.html#L_vol_table_det